# GAM distributed lag model with factor smooth interaction (by variable)

Tags: r, matrix, gam, mgcv, contrast

I'm trying to compare the climate response in the last 60 years of two subgroups of a plant (factor variable `subgroups` with 2 levels). The response of the two subgroups which both grew on the same plots is measured in deviation from the long-term growth (`plant_growth`). As climate data mean temperature (`tmean`) and mean precipitation (`prec`) are available.
I formulated a distributed lag model using `mgcv`'s `gam()` to test the hypothesis, that the climate response differs between the plant subgroups:

```
climate_model <- gam(plant_growth ~ te(tmean, lag, by = subgroups) +
                                    te(prec, lag, , by = subgroups) +
                                    te(tmean, prec, lag, , by = subgroups) ,
                                  data = plant_data)
```

`plant_data` is a list that contains `tmean`, `prec` and `lag` as separate numeric matrices, `subgroups` as factor variable which distinguishes between subgroup A and B, a character variable giving the `ID` of the plant, and the numeric measured `plant_growth` as vector.

The problem is, however, that factor `by` variables cannot be used with the matrix arguments from `plant_data`. The error message looks as follows:

```
Error in smoothCon(split$smooth.spec[[i]], data, knots, absorb.cons, scale.penalty = scale.penalty,  : 
  factor `by' variables can not be used with matrix arguments.
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to include the factor variable `subgroups` into the distributed lag model so that a comparison between the two levels of the factor is possible.

I've already tried running two separate lag models for the two levels of *subgroups*. This works fine. However, I cannot really compare the predictions of the two models because the fit and the parameters of the smooths are different. Moreover, in this way the the climate response of the two subgroups is treated as if it was completely independent. This is however not the case.

I was reproduce my problem with growth data from the Treeclim package:

```
library("treeclim") #Data library
data("muc_spruce") #Plant growth
data("muc_clim") #Climate data

#Format climate to wide
clim <- pivot_wider(muc_clim, names_from = month, values_from = c(temp,prec))

#Format the growth data and add three new groth time series
growth <- muc_spruce %>%
            select(-samp.depth) %>%
            mutate(year = as.numeric(row.names(muc_spruce))) %>%
            mutate(ID = 1) %>%
            rename("plant_growth" = "mucstd")

additional_growth <- data.frame()
for (i in c(1:3)){
  
A <- growth %>%
  mutate(plant_growth = plant_growth + runif(nrow(muc_spruce), min = 0, max = 0.5)) %>%
  mutate(ID = ID + i)

additional_growth <- rbind(additional_growth, A)
}

growth <- rbind(growth, additional_growth)

#Bring growth and climate data together
plant_data <- na.omit(left_join(growth, clim))
rm(A, growth, clim, muc_clim, muc_spruce, additional_growth, i) #clean

#Add the subgroups label
plant_data$subgroups <- as.factor(c(rep("A", nrow(plant_data)/2), rep("B", nrow(plant_data)/2)))

#Format for gam input
plant_data <- list(lag = matrix(1:12,nrow(plant_data),12,byrow=TRUE),
                       year = plant_data$year,
                       ID = plant_data$ID,
                       plant_growth = plant_data$plant_growth,
                       subgroups = as.factor(plant_data$subgroups),
                       tmean = data.matrix(plant_data[,c(4:15)]),
                       prec = data.matrix(plant_data[,c(16:27)]))
```

Comment: Can you share a data sample for testing?

Comment: Thank you for having a look at my problem! Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are challenging to implement, but fortunately they are possible. As the response above suggests, if you look at the help for linear functionals (`?mgcv::linear.functional.terms` and `?mgcv::gam.models`), you will see that the `by` variable is used as a weighting matrix, and the resulting smooth is constructed as `rowSums(L*F)`, where `F` is your distributed lag smooth and `L` is the weighting matrix. I spent a lot of time on this for a few recent projects, and finally realised that I needed to supply group-level distributed lag terms *for each group* in the formula (this is reasonably well-described here: https://github.com/nicholasjclark/portal_VAR). In short, you can create weight matrices for each level of the grouping factor for setting up group-level distributed lag terms:

```
weights_l1 <- weights_l2 <- matrix(1, ncol = ncol(plant_data$lag), 
                                   nrow = nrow(plant_data$lag))
```

For each level in the grouping factor, the rows in its weighting matrix need to have `1`s when the corresponding observation in the data matches that series, and `0`s otherwise

```
weights_l1[!(plant_data$subgroups == levels(plant_data$subgroups)[1], ] <- 0
plant_data$weights_l1 <- weights_l1

weights_l2[!(plant_data$subgroups == levels(plant_data$subgroups)[2], ] <- 0
plant_data$weights_l2 <- weights_l2
```

Now you are ready to fit a model with different distributed lag terms per level of the grouping factor

```
climate_model <- gam(plant_growth ~ 
                       te(tmean, lag, by = weights_l1) +
                       te(tmean, lag, by = weights_l2) +
                       te(prec, lag, by = weights_l1) +
                       te(prec, lag, by = weights_l2),
                     data = plant_data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer and the thorough explanation! This has brought me a big step forward. Unfortunately, my research project is already finished but I hope that this answer is helpful to others struggling with something similar.

Comment: My pleasure Anna, a shame I didn't see it sooner. But yes, hopefully it'll be useful to someone else along the way

Comment: For those interested in doing this in practice, I have a small blog post showing how it can be done. I believe this will be helpful because some care needs to be taken when setting up the data matrices: https://ecogambler.netlify.app/blog/distributed-lags-mgcv/

Answer (score 0):

From `?mgcv::linear.functional.terms`:

> The mechanism is usable with random effect smooths which take factor arguments, by using a trick to create a 2D array of factors. Simply create a factor vector containing the columns of the factor matrix stacked end to end (column major order). Then reset the dimensions of this vector to create the appropriate 2D array: the first dimension should be the number of response data and the second the number of columns of the required factor matrix. You can not use matrix or data.matrix to set up the required matrix of factor levels. See example below:

```
## set up a `factor matrix'...
fac <- factor(sample(letters,n*2,replace=TRUE))
dim(fac) <- c(n,2)
```

You cannot create a factor matrix tough, but can create a factor and modify the dims afterwars.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem, however, remained. As long as I have factors (even if it is the dim-modified matrix version of it), the model does not run.